# Let $G$ be an abelian group. Show that the mapping $\phi:G\to G$ given by $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Show that the mapping $\phi:G\to G$ give by $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$. Show that if $G$ were not abelian, then $\phi$ would not be an automorphism.

Okay so this is broken down into two cases;

- case $1$: $G$ is abelian then $\phi$ is an automorphism
- case $2$: $G$ is non-abelian then $\phi$ is NOT a automorphism

For case $1$: I want to show that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$, $\phi$ is $1$-$1$, and $\phi$ is onto, but I'm not sure how to do so.

For case $2$: I want to show that $\phi(xy)\ne\phi(x)\phi(y)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! We use Mathjax here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference :)

Comment: I think I have figured out case 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $\phi$ is surjective (onto):

Let $x \in G$ then $\phi(x^-1) = (x^{-1})^{-1} = x$ so clearly $\phi$ is surjective (onto).

To prove $\phi$ is injective (one-to-one):

Let $x \in G$ then $\phi(x) = \phi(y) \Rightarrow x^{-1} = y^{-1} \Rightarrow yx^{-1}x = yy^{-1}x \Rightarrow y = x$.

To prove $\phi$ is a homomorphism:

$\phi(xy) = (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1} =\phi(x)\phi(y)$ (abelian property)

Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism and bijective it is an automorphism.

If $G$ was not abelian then: $\phi(xy) = (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} \neq x^{-1}y^{-1} =\phi(x)\phi(y)$. The abelian property implies that $xy = yx$ so if $G$ is not abelian then $xy \neq yx$ for at least one pair of elements in $G$, thus $\phi$ fails to be a homomorphism in this case.

Comment: I think this is beautifully written up and I appreciate your help. +1

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\phi(xy)=(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$, and we know that $\phi(x)\varphi(y)=x^{-1}y^{-1}$.

In the abelian case (hence our group is commutative), we have that $$\forall x, y \in G:\;\phi(xy) = (xy)^{-1} = \underbrace{y^{-1}x^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}}_{\text{commutative property}} = \phi(x) \phi(y)$$

Without commutativity, we do ***not*** have that $$\forall x, y \in G:\;\;\phi(xy) = (xy)^{-1} = \underbrace{y^{-1}x^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}}_{\text{DOESN'T WORK}\;\large\forall x, y} = \phi(x) \phi(y)$$

Comment: so since G is not abelian then it is not commutative therefore, ϕ(xy)=/=ϕ(x)ϕ(y)

Comment: Exactly! In the second case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have completed the problem with ease!

Comment: You're welcome, Arnold!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Just follow the definitions. By definition $\varphi(xy)=(xy)^{-1}$, and $\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=x^{-1}y^{-1}$; what does $(xy)^{-1}$ simplify to in general?

Comment: I did so and have figured out case 1 easily, but i'm not sure how to complete case 2

Comment: @Arnold: Same idea: if $G$ is **not** Abelian, then there are $x,y\in G$ such that $xy\ne yx$. Now consider $\varphi(x^{-1}y^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** In the first case, show that $\ker(\varphi)=\{e\}$ which implies injectivity. To show surjectivity, try to find an element that maps to $g$ for each $g\in G$. Use the fact $G$ is abelian to conclude that it is a homomorphism.

In the second case, I prefer the contrapositive: if $\varphi$ is an automorphism, then $G$ is abelian.