# Characterize the groups $G$ for which the map $\iota: G \to G$, sending $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$, is an automorphism of $G$

Tags: group-theory, inverse, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

I have trouble on this question:
"Characterize the groups G for which the map $$\iota: G \to G$$ sending $$x \mapsto x^{-1}$$ for all $x \in G$, is an automorphism of $G$."

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573542/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-show-that-the-mapping-phig-to-g-given-by-phi) post I have seen that $G$ must be abelian. Can anyone propose another characteristic of $G$ that I can derive from the given conditions besides abelian? Thank you so much!!

Comment: As the post implies with cases 1 and 2, this is an "if and only if" statement.  That is, this map will be an automorphism *if and only if* $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I do not understand what "promote another characteristic" means. This is probably google translation from something in Chinese. In every commutative group the inversion is an automorphism. Is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: Well the inversion map is certainly an isomorphism for abelian groups, and you say you have already seen this is true for abelian groups. This means that any condition you give will be equivalent to being abelian. There are a host of conditions  equivalent to being abelian.

Comment: @studiosus Did I use the wrong word here? I guess if I use "propose", it will be better?

Comment: Your words are fine, the idea is wrong.  The only characteristic of $G$ that matters here is whether it is abelian.  If it is abelian, the map will be an automorphism.  If $G$ is not abelian, then the map will not be an automorphism.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Got it! I was a little bit ambiguous because the question is to characterize the group G, and I was wondering if there are more characteristics of G. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome.  It's easy to see that every abelian group fits, it's a little harder to see that the only groups that fit here are the abelian ones.

Comment: Well, another characteristic of $G$ would be that $Aut(G)$ has even order! By the way, the smallest non-trivial group with odd order automorphism group has order $729=3^6$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is a one to one and onto function on $G$ since every group element has a unique inverse.

Thus if $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for every pair in $G$ then it is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$. But that means that $y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ $\implies$ $xy=yx$ for all pair in $G$ thus, $G$ is abelian.

Conversly if $G$ is abelian you can trivially show it is an isomorphism. Since it is an "if and only if condition", it is an "necessary and sufficient" condition. (You don't need to search for another condition.)

Comment: But the question is: *Can anyone propose another characteristic of $G$ that I can derive from the given conditions besides abelian?*  This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question asked is: "Can we suggest a new property of $G$ that can be deduced from the current conditions, other than it being abelian?" From the above discussion, it is clear that this is only possible if $G$ is abelian, which implies that we cannot make any additional statements. If there is anything to say about $G$, it must be due to its abelian nature. So, this does answer the question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry.