# Proving $f(a) = a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism iff $G$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

**Problem.**

Let $G$ be a group. Define a function $f : G \longrightarrow G$ by for all $a \in G$, $f(a) = a^{-1}$.

Prove that $f$ is a homomorphism **if and only if** $G$ is commutative.

---

**My attempt.**

Assume G is commutative;

Then $$f(x * y) = (x * y)^{-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x * y) = y^{-1} * x^{-1}$$ Note: *(am I making this up? I remember this from linear algebra and seem to recall it from this course as well.)*

$$\Rightarrow f(y) * f(x) = f(x) * f(y)$$ as $G$ is commutative.

Let us now assume that $G$ is homomorphism;

$$f(x * y) = f(x) * f(y)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x * y) = x^{-1} * y^{-1}$$

At this point I would try to show that $$x^{-1} * y^{-1} \neq y^{-1} * x^{-1}$$

Does not work and therefore it has to be commutative as well, but I don't want to spend more energy on this before knowing that I am doing this right and not just making things up! Thank you.

Comment: you can find the answer here,your answer is almost done. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674695/characterize-the-groups-g-for-which-the-map-iota-g-to-g-sending-x-maps/675617#675617

Comment: This question sends me to yet other questions which in the end become unrelated. I would like to just receive a simple answer on my question.

Comment: if you read the answer it is the aswer :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all, for the answers! Very much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome,when you have question, don't hesitate to ask,I am speaking like owner of the site.Beside joke,I hope it is useful for  you.

Comment: Why is my question receiving down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $f$ is a homomorphism, then 
$$
f((xy)^{-1})=xy
$$
by definition, but also
\begin{align}
f((xy)^{-1})&=f(y^{-1}x^{-1}) &&\text{basic identity}\\
&=f(y^{-1})f(x^{-1}) &&\text{homomorphism}\\
&=\dots
\end{align}

For the other direction your reasoning is correct.

Comment: To  complete your answer and to be sure that I am understanding you correctly:

$$=y * x$$ $$= y * x = x * y$$.

Yes?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

- If $a=b$ then $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$ so $f(a)=f(b)$ which means that $f$ is well-defined.
- We have  $f(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ which equals to $a^{-1}b^{-1}=f(a)f(b)$ if $G$ is abelian and therefor $f$ is a homomorphism.
- If $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism then think about $f(a^{-1}b^{-1})$.
- The same claim is correct if $f\in Aut(G)$.

Comment: Very nice, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two lines 
$$y^{-1}*x^{-1}=(x*y)^{-1}=f(x*y)$$

$$x^{-1}*y^{-1}=f(x)*f(y)$$

The terms at the left are equal if and only if $G$ is commutative (since every element can be written as the inverse of another element). The terms at the right are equal if and only if $f$ is a homomorphism.