# How to show that $\phi(g)=g^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism iff $G$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

For a group $(G,\cdot)$, show that $G$ is abelian if and only if the map $\phi:G\to G$ defined by $$\phi(g)=g^{-1}$$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you made any progress in either direction?

Comment: sorry, no, I know it seems like im asking ppl to do my hw but thats not wht im trying to do cuz i have no idea how to even start

Comment: You could start by writing down the properties that a homomorphism must have, and trying to check them. You could also look at how that map behaves in several small groups, some abelian and some not.

Comment: See also: [Prove: A group $G$ is abelian if and only if the map $G\rightarrow G$ given by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872952) and [Characterize the groups $G$ for which the map $\iota: G \to G$, sending $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$, is an automorphism of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/674695)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is abelian. You need to show $\phi(gh) = \phi(g) \phi(h)$ for all $g,h \in G$. If you write down the definitions of $\phi(gh)$, $\phi(g)$, and $\phi(h)$, you should be almost done.

---

Suppose $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Given any $g,h \in G$, how can you show $gh = hg$ using the definition of $\phi$ being a homomorphism? (The previous part should give you some intuition.)

Answer (score 0):

$\phi$ is a homomorphism $\iff \phi(g^{-1}h^{-1})=\phi (g^{-1})\phi(h^{-1})\iff (g^{-1}h^{-1})^{-1}=gh\iff hg=gh\forall g,h\in G\iff G$  is abelian.

Here I have used the "socks and shoes property" of inverses:  $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: if G is Abelian we should have ${\phi(a \cdot b)=\phi(b \cdot a)}$ , now ${\phi(a \cdot b)= a^{-1 }\cdot b^{-1} = (b\cdot a)^{-1}  = \phi(b\cdot a) }$ This implies ${\phi(a\cdot b) = \phi(b \cdot a)}$