# Prove: A group $G$ is abelian if and only if the map $G\rightarrow G$ given by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

**Problem:** A group $G$ is abelian if and only if the map $G\rightarrow G$ given by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism. Prove it.

**Solution:** $(\Rightarrow)$ If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $x_1^{-1}=x_2^{-1}\Rightarrow x_2=x_1$, by multiplying both sides by $x_1x_2$ and the assumption that $G$ is commutative. Thus $f$ is injective. Also, since $G$ is a group, $\forall x\in G, \exists x^{-1}\in G; xx^{-1}=e_G$ which proves that $f$ is surjective.

$(\Leftarrow)$ $\forall x,y\in G; xy=\Big((xy)^{-1}\Big)^{-1}=f\Big(f(xy)\Big)=f(y^{-1}x^{-1})$, but since $G$ is a automorphism (and therefore a homomorphism), $xy=f(y^{-1})f(x^{-1})=yx \square$

Anything wrong with the solution?

Comment: Seems OK, at least the second half. A more direct way for the "if" direction is

$$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=xyf(x)f(y)=xyf(xy)=(xy)(xy)^{-1}=e$$

What do you mean by $G$ is injective/surjective?

Comment: One doesn't say the group $G$ is injective, one says the map $f$ is injective. I think a better way to prove bijectivity is to exhibit itself as its own inverse, i.e. $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $G$ is abelian or not; the map will be bijective regardless. What I think you're meant to show is that the map is a _homomorphism_ iff $G$ is abelian (a bijective homomorphism is the same as an isomorphism).

Comment: @Arthur The problem is directly put from Hungerford's *Algebra*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/573542/8581.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is abelian then the map $x\to x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism:
$$(ab)^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$$
If $x\to x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism, $G$ is abelian:
$$ab=(b^{-1}a^{-1})^{-1}=((ba)^{-1})^{-1}=ba$$

---

$x\to x^{-1}$ is a bijection as proved in the question. So if it is a homomorphism, it is an automorphism.

Comment: Yes, a *lot* simpler!

Comment: It is also true that [$f^2=\mathrm{id}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2842290/721644)  since $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x,\forall x\in G.$