# Show function is an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism

Given $(G,*)$ a group. Show the function $f: G \to   G$ defined as $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is an isomorphism if and only if G is abelian.

I am having troubles showing both ways of the proof. I know I have to show that $a*b=b*a$ for the first part, but do I have to suppose that the function is bijective or just use that $f(a*b)=f(a)*f(b)$?

For the second part, knowing that G is abelian, do I have to show that the function is bijective and $f(a*b)=f(a)*f(b)$ is true?

Comment: An isomorphism and a  bijective map, I think you can use any of the properties or both without having any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe that for every $a,b\in G$

$(a*b)*(b^{-1}*a^{-1})=a*(b*b^{-1})a^{-1}=$

$=a*1*a^{-1}=a*a^{-1}=1$

so for the unicity of inverse you have that

$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$

For every $a,b\in G$

$f(a*b)=(a*b)^{-1}=b^{-1}*a^{-1}=$

$=a^{-1}*b^{-1}=f(a)*f(b)$

so the map is a morphism.

$f(a)=1 \to a^{-1}=1$ and so $a=1$

so the map is injective

If $a\in G$ than

$f(a^{-1})=(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$

so the map is also surjective

Conversely, if $f$ is an isomorphism than

$a*b=f((a*b)^{-1})=$

$=f(b^{-1}*a^{-1})=f(b^{-1})*f(a^{-1})=b*a$

Comment: Can you explain me why $(a∗b)^{−1}=b^{−1}∗a^{−1}$ works? Is it valid to use commutative property to show is Abelian?

Comment: I changed the answer, it is clearer now?  other question?

Comment: @Jorge How can it be valid to use commutative property to show commutativity(=abelian)?

Comment: Thank you! It is clear now.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it isn´t, but the step I was talking about used it. Given the first part of the proof, after the question was changed, it is now possible to use that assumption.

Answer (score 4):

For any group $G$, the map

$f(g) = g^{-1}, \; g \in G, \tag 1$

is *always* a bijection:  the quickest way to see this, I think, is to note that

$f^2(g) = f(f(g)) = f(g^{-1}) = (g^{-1})^{-1} = g, \tag 2$

so that

$f^2 = \mathbf 1_G, \tag 3$

the identity mapping on $G$:

$\mathbf 1_G(g) = g, \; \forall g \in G; \tag 4$

thus, from (2), (3),

$f(g) = f^{-1}(g), \; \forall g \in G, \tag 5$

that is, $f$ is its own inverse.  Since any invertible map from any set to itself is bijective, so is $f:G \to G$.

If now $G$ is abelian,

$f(g_1 g_2) = (g_1 g_2)^{-1} = g_2^{-1} g_1^{-1} = g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1} = f(g_1) f(g_2), \tag 6$

which shows that $f$ is a homomorphism; this combined with the bijectivity of $f$ indicates it is an isomorphism.

Conversely, if $f$ is an isomorphism, then

$g_2^{-1} g_1^{-1} = (g_1 g_2)^{-1} = f(g_1 g_2) = f(g_1) f(g_2) = g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1}, \tag 7$

whence

$g_1 g_2 = (g_2^{-1} g_1^{-1})^{-1} = (g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1})^{-1} = g_2 g_1, \; \forall g_1, g_2 \in G, \tag 8$

which shows that $G$ is abelian indeed.